# Inserting a value into a table if it matches the criteria otherwise insert null

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to `insert` a value into a table using a value of `SUBSTR(data, 71, 2)`.

However if data isn't long enough then I want to input `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `CASE` expression here:

```
CASE WHEN LENGTH(data) >= 73
     THEN SUBSTR(data, 71, 2)
     ELSE NULL END
```

This would be part of your larger insert statement, which you did not reveal to us.

**Edit:**

Calling `SUBSTR` on a column with a starting position which is out of bounds will already return `NULL`.  However, if the starting position is within bounds and the length exceeds the length of the string, then only the available remainder of the string will be returned.  Hence, the following call to `SUBSTR` will return `world`:

```
SUBSTR('hello world', 7, 30)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, That's perfect. Thanks for your help.